# WordPress Ninja Forms date picker

Tags: wordpress, forms, ninja-forms

I have WordPress site with form made with Ninja Forms plugin. There is a need to pick a date (to allow user to choose some date) with a calendar. I mean the date field, so when user clicks on it calendar is shown which allows to choose day and month. Actually I thought that there must be built-in plugin field type "date" but there is no such thing. Maybe I should use other form building WordPress plugin or add some additional code in existing one? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The very latest version of Ninja Forms do include Date field (probably it's been available for some time):

See first row, 2nd field.

[image]

On the front-end you should see something like this once you click on it:

[image]

Alternative options:

1. If you familiar with PHP/JS you can create a custom add-on for Ninja Forms that would extend NF_Fields_Textbox class and load your preferred datapicker libraries (jQuery Datepicker, pickadate.js, etc).
2. Less elegant solution could be loading extra css/js files from your functions.php file and making sure that required classes are added to field/wrapper.